# How to restore a previous version of an Infopath form when changes were made to the template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, versioning

We are working on a SharePoint 2013 Environment. We recently made changes to the form template and published it. We are able to access the new template by opening up a new form from the Document library but the Issue is that it has also updated forms that were submitted previously to the document library.

I checked the Form Option (Versioning) settings in Infopath and it is set to "Do Nothing" to update existing forms. Not sure how the existing forms got updated. Anyways I really need to restore the existing forms to the previous version. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can you check if version history is enabled on the library and see if the older version is there for an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my testing results in SharePoint 2013, all existing forms created from the template will automatically use the latest form template of the library. 
Only the uploaded forms will not be updated by default.

To restore the template for the existing forms, you need to manually re-store the template file to previous one as the template file doesn't have versioning history. Publish the old template to a new form library, and then move the existing forms to this new library. Relink the forms in the new document library to the the published form template.

How to relink the existing forms:

1. Open the form library
2. Switch to Relink Documents view

   [image]
3. In the Relink column, select the check box for each form that you want to link to the new form template.
4. On the list toolbar, click Relink.
5. Or, click Relink All to relink all files

   [image]
6. After the files are relinked to the previous template, you can download the files and upload them back to the original library if you want.

   The form template of the uploaded forms will not be updated if you update the form template of the library unless relinking the files.

Comment: This really helped! Thank You! Am I correct that if we make changes to a template and publish that to a Document Library A, the forms in a Document Library B (These forms would be transferred from A to B before publishing the change) won't be affected by the change?

Comment: What would be the best way to prevent this from happening in the future?-Download/Re-upload the forms in the library before making the change

Comment: If we save the old InfoPath forms as a pdf would that help?

Comment: Yes, you can save them as pdf

Comment: The template of lib B will not be changes because this form template is published to lib A.